# Смена пароля root в Linux с помощью LiveCD

Tags: linux

Имеется SD карта с Linux на котором надо сбросить пароль и флэшка с Ubuntu 16.04LTS которую я запускаю без установки.

Что я делаю не так? Как я понял надо смонтировать образ SD карты к Ubuntu и потом сменить пароль root для Linux на Flash карте с помощью команды passwd, но эта команда не хочет работать даже просто в консоли, это из-за того что Ubuntu запущена в демонстрационном режиме?

Comment: `chroot`  на флэшку забыл

Comment: Приведите ваш диалог с системой, какие команды вы вводите и что получаете в ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

если вы примонтировали корневой раздел системы, в которой надо сменить пароль, в каталог, например, `/mnt`, то сменить пароль пользователя `root` в этой системе можно, воспользовавшись программой *chroot*:

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt passwd
```

или ей же, но неявно, через опцию `-R` (`--root`) программы *passwd*:

```
$ sudo passwd -R /mnt
```

Comment: В таком методе есть два "подводных камня": 1) Для того, что бы "примонтировать корневой раздел системы" надо его сначала ОТмонтировать.... И как Вы собираетесь отмонтировать '/' во время работы системы?! 2) В этой не очень понятной ситуации у Вас должны уже быть права root-а... Откуда они у Вас взялись ?

Comment: @Sergey, 2. загружена live-система, в которой по умолчанию у пользователя имеется право использования sudo. 1. монтируется корень **другой** системы, не той, которая загружена.

Answer (score -4):

"Сменить" пароль невозможно в принципе. Он хранится в зашифрованном виде и его не знает никто, кроме самого пользователя.

То, что Вы называете "сменить" делается в два этапа:
1) ОТМЕНИТЬ пароль пользователя root
2) УСТАНОВИТЬ пароль пользователя root

Шаг 2 выполняется штатными средствами с помощью команды passwd, когда ОС работает в обычном режиме.

А вот шаг 1 можно выполнить только если ОС работает в ОДНОПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОМ режие - это аварийный режим восстановления системы.

Как загрузить ОС в таком режиме, зависит от системного загрузчика, используемого для загрузки ОС. В большинстве случаев, надо успеть попасть в меню выбора режима загрузки и выбрать там пункт "Однопользовательский режим".

После этого идём в каталог /etc  и любым текстовым редактором правим файл passwd, делая второе поле в строке root пустым, вот так 'root::'. После чего перезагружаемся в обычном режиме.

Однако, скорее всего, это всё окажется бесполезным, так как современные  версии Linux не позволяют входить в систему под логином root в принципе! Никак! Свидетельство тому - символ 'x' или '*' в поле пароля root-а в файле "shadow".  Это говорит о том, что от имени root можно запускать процессы, но залогиниться под root-ом невозможно.

Comment: Что-то вы странное рассказываете. Невозможно узнать старый пароль рута. Изменить на новый - элементарно. Нужны лишь только права рута в текущей системе либо доступ к диску из совершенно любой другой системы. Что автор вопроса и делает - загружается в другую систему.

Comment: @Sergey, последний абзац ответа (который начинается с «однако») содержит **точно** неверную информацию.

Comment: **последний абзац ответа (который начинается с «однако») содержит точно неверную информацию** - попробуйте залогиниться root-ом в Ubuntu :-) О результате - напишите!

Comment: **Невозможно узнать старый пароль рута. Изменить на новый - элементарно. ** - очень интересные рассуждения! Т.е. мы **элементарно** можем ИЗМЕНИТЬ то, чего не знаем?! Я сказал вполне определённо - можно СБРОСИТЬ пароль рута, но ИЗМЕНИТЬ его невозможно.

Comment: **Нужны лишь только права рута в текущей системе** - И как Вы собираетесь получить права рута, не зная его пароля? :-) Я чётко сказал - нужно загрузить систему в ОДНОПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОМ режиме! В этом режиме само понятия прав доступа теряет смысл. А вот как это сделать - зависит от конкретной версии ОС и загрузчика. На крайний случай, можно даже отцепить HDD и прицепить к другому компу, на котором у Вас есть учётная запись.

Comment: @Sergey, *попробуйте залогиниться root-ом в Ubuntu* — `sudo -i`

Comment: @Sergey, *На крайний случай, можно даже отцепить HDD и прицепить к другому компу, на котором у Вас есть учётная запись.* — автор вопроса фактически именно это и делает.

Comment: **sudo -i** Читаем man: "-i, --login
                 Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
                 resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell."  И причём тут пользователь root ?

Comment: **автор вопроса фактически именно это и делает** - но тогда я не понимаю, зачем все эти разговоры про root?

Comment: При загрузке в single user mode, операционная система в целях безопасности спрашивает пароль root'а.

Comment: **операционная система ... спрашивает пароль**  - что бы не быть голословным, проверил на своём станке. У меня Ubuntu 14,04.  В момент перезагрузки системы зашёл в меню и выбрал пункт "Drop to shell prompt". Как и ожидалось, никто  никакого пароля не спрашивал. Команда id выдала "id=0(root), gid=0(root)".

Comment: Но есть тонкость. Ubuntu 14.04 уже не использует файл "inittab". В более старых системах, в которых этот файл используется. там надо было задать в меню ranlevel=1.

Comment: @Sergey, *`sudo -i` И причём тут пользователь root ?* — выполните указанную команду — будет запущен login-shell именно пользователя root. в чём можете убедиться любым доступным способом: `whoami`, `id`, `logname` ...

Comment: **в чём можете убедиться любым доступным способом** - таким вариантом команды sudo  я не пользовался. Обычно делал так: sudo mc. Вызов id.. даёт тот же самый результат. Вот только при входе в режим sudo система спрашивает ВАШ пароль, а не рута.

Comment: Я проделал такой любопытный эксперимент: 1) Вошёл в shell через sudo. 2) Выдал команду  passwd (вроде бы - для root). 3) Ctrl/Alt/F1 и логинюсь под root (!!!) с новым паролем... Что это означает на самом деле - не представляю.

Comment: А вообще, поднятый TS вопрос очень подробно разжёвывается тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/54103/